# Mockito with static class and method returning void

Tags: java, junit, mockito, powermockito

I am trying to change the implementation of a method using Mockito when the method is called, but I have two issues at the same time 1) my class is static and 2) my method returns void.

```
PowerMockito.doAnswer(new Answer<Void>() {
        public Void answer(InvocationOnMock invocation) throws IOException {
            DeliveryQueue.publishToQueue(testQueue, "message");
            return null;
        }
    }).when(DeliveryQueue).publishToQueue(DeliveryQueue.REAL_QUEUE, "message");
```

As you can see I'm trying to tell my test that when we publish a message to the `REAL_QUEUE`, we should actually be sending it to the `testQueue`. `REAL_QUEUE` is `static final` so it's not possible to change it directly (I tried reflection without success). The problem currently is  that `when(DeliveryQueue)` won't work as it expects a mocked object even if I've used `PowerMockito.mockstatic(DeliveryQueue.class)` just above. I've also tried `when(DeliveryQueue.getInstance())` but it's not tagged as being the mocked object either.

Answer (score 1):

Did you add `@PrepareForTest(DeliveryQueue.class)` at class level?

Try this: `.when(DeliveryQueue.class); DeliveryQueue.publishToQueue(DeliveryQueue.REAL_QUEUE, "message");`

Comment: Yes I did. The problem seems to just occure in compilation at `when(DeliveryQueue)`.

Comment: Try this: `.when(DeliveryQueue.class); DeliveryQueue.publishToQueue(DeliveryQueue.REAL_QUEUE, "message");`